# Bootstrap 3 Irregular Panel Layout

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, layout, panel

Wondering how to achieve a layout like pictured in the attached image. I'm guessing it's a mess of columns and rows but I've tried several different ways and can't seem to get it. Unless I'm approaching this from the wrong direction?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's do-able with Bootstrap, but the columns must have a defined height..

http://codeply.com/go/5sGEBmNdMv

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Makes sense. I was trying a table approach but that was not scaling nicely so this may be a better answer. Thanks for the structural help on it!